# What does “seconds on toast” mean?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, meaning-in-context, nouns

I read “Kafka on the shore” and met the next sentence:

> I look around,
>   and **seconds on toast** don't seem likely to materialize.

Could you explain what “seconds on toast” mean? What is semantically and syntactically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He thinks he will not be able to get a second serving of toast.

> **second** ORDINAL NUMBER
>   1.7 (**seconds**) *informal*
>   A second course or second helping of food at a meal.
>   [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/second)